# Whats the sense of using query parameters in react?

Tags: reactjs, query-string

I want to know why and when I should exactly use queryParameters. If I have a child component, that affects the state of the parent component, I can simply parse the setState method to the child component, so why do many people use queryStrings here? Writing the code to modify the query string of the url is a lot more writing than just simply calling the setState function.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a situation where for example after clicking on some button you want to switch to another page that is details page. To be able to do that you have to pass ID of element to know which details you want to show. That's why you use `queryParameters` to pass it to another component. This component doesn't have to be child or parent of previous one so you cannot just use `setState` for that here.